# Throwing Exception in a nested Flowable's onNext is causing an UndeliverableException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

I've code like this in a repository:

```
return Completable.fromAction {
    // Some code
    loginService.login(id)
        .subscribe(
            { response ->
                if(response.isNotSuccessful()) {
                    throw Exception()
                }
                // Some code
            },
            { e ->
                throw e
            }
    )
}
```

I've code like this in a `ViewModel`:

```
fun onLoginAction(id) {
    repository.login(id)
        .subscribe(
            {
                showSuccess()
            },
            {
                showFailure()
            }
    )
}
```

Basically, the `ViewModel` calls the login method in the repository which returns the `Completable`.

This results in an `UndeliverableException` when the response is not successful. I want the `Completable`'s subscriber's `onError()` method to be called. How do I do this?

Comment: Undeliverable exceptions happen when there's no subscriber to receive the Error Event. Check if you're not disposing before the exception happens. It's helpful if you paste your code here.

Comment: @Fred I've posted the simplified version of my code

Comment: ok, thanks, but I'd need also the subscription to the completable, meaning how you are subscribing to the completable stream

Comment: @Fred I've added the subscription to the completable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough knowledge to actually say this with certainty, but I still think this has some value to you and it's too big for a comment.

Here's what I think it's happening. When `onError` fails rx won't run this through the same observable stream. Instead, it will propagate this to the RxPlugins error handler and eventually to the default exception handler in your system. You can find this [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling).

This is to say that when `loginService.login(id)` throws the exception in the `onError`, the `Completable` stream won't have a chance to catch it and forward it to the `onError` of the outer subscribe. In other words, the completable stream is independent of the login service one.

Usually, you'd want to create one single stream and let the view model subscribe to it. If you have more than one stream, rx has loads of operators to help you chain these. Try and make the repository return one stream from the service. Something like this:

```
fun login(id) = loginService.login(id)
```

And now on the view model, you can check if the call was or not successful using the same method - `response.isNotSuccessful()`

Comment: Basically, I am performing some write operations when I recieve the data. I want to expose when all that is completed using a Completable. What can I do if I want to use a Completable?

Comment: There are loads of methods. Singles have `ignoreElement` for example. This converts them to completables. If you'd like to do operations with side effects like writing, I'd recommend the `doOn<xyz>` methods. You could use for example `doOnSucess` to write the received data and then use `ignoreElement`

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for your help :). If no one gives a better solution within 24 hours, I'll accept your answer